# On blur event triggering http call, blocking the next action

Tags: javascript

I have scenrio where I'm making http call on blur event of an element and click event on another element. 
Found that click event is not trigger if user click event until http call completes(Infact user has to click second time to trigger click action)

Here is sample code:

```html
<input type="email" id="email" name="email"
    onblur="profileCheckAPICall" placeholder="Email Adddress" />
<button onClick="triggerNextScreen">Next</button>
```

In the above code "profileCheckAPICall" method is making a http call. "triggerNextScreen" is method which trigger to move to next screen.

Issue:
User need to click twice on Next button if blur event overlap with the click event (User input email and directly click on button without navigating to any other fields.)

I was trying with event.relatedTarget approach but it is not feasible for me as the button element part of CMS page, which I may not have control over that. Can you suggest some better approach to handle the above case.

Comment: How are you making the HTTP request? Are you using `XMLHttpRequest`?

Comment: No, using axios library making a post call(Ref: [link](https://github.com/axios/axios))..

Comment: I don't know what's happening, then. Could you edit the question to share more details? Try to give us a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).